# Installing Solr on Debian 8.1

Tags: solr, debian-jessie

I managed to get **Solr** installed on my last server, but I can't seem to figure it out this time. I've followed the details here (not directly for Debian 8.1, but the same instructions worked on my Debian 7 install)

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-solr-on-ubuntu-14-04

So I did:

```
sudo apt-get -y install openjdk-7-jdk
mkdir /usr/java
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64 /usr/java/default
sudo apt-get -y install solr-jetty
```

Then, as "root" on the server in SSH, I'm doing

`lynx http://localhost:8080/solr/admin`

..but I get an error:

`Alert!: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`

Its almost like Solr isn't running - but I'm sure it was this simple last time.

Anyone got any suggestions?

**UPDATE:** If I check to see if a java process is running for it, I don't see anything about start.jar (which I would expect);

```
root@server:~# ps aux | grep "java"
tomcat7   4606  0.2  7.2 1056076 73472 ?       Sl   14:42   0:11 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat7/endorsed -classpath /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat7 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat7 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/tomcat7-tomcat7-tmp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
root      5232  0.0  0.2  12720  2268 pts/0    S+   16:05   0:00 grep java
```

...so it kinda makes me think its not running

**UPDATE 2:**  I have uninstalled **solr-jetty**, and put in **solr-tomcat**. It now *does* load, BUT only when I access it via SSH, using:

[image]

lynx http://localhost:8080/solr/admin

However, if I try and access it from a browser using:

http://123.123.123.123:8080/solr/admin (IP taken out)

...then all it does is hang,and eventually die :/

**NB:** I've got it working now on the site (as the script uses "localhost" to connect anyway) - but could do with getting it working via IP as well, if I ever need to check it out :))

Comment: Well, is it running?

Comment: @EEAA - please see my update above

Comment: By default solr runs on port 8983.